# Error Error: Unsupported attribute standardcontoller in <apex:page>

Tags: error

i am getting the error for the below code. any solution???

```
<apex:page standardstylesheets="false"  showheader="false" sidebar="false"
standardContoller= " Merchandise_c" recordsetvariable="products">

<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.styles,'styles.css')}"/>


  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->


  <h1>Inventory count sheet</h1>

  This is your new Page: countsheet


  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi user24655, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The more details you provide, particularly code you've written, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer you'll find helpful.

Comment: The only unusual thing I see is white space at the start of the value of standardController. Try removing that.

Comment: I get that sometimes, especially when I copy and past. Try deleting the <apex:page lines and then put <apex:page> then save. Then retype manually the remaining information then save

Comment: I am surprised none of us detected the spell error the user is doing .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava - I cannot tell you how many hours I have spent over the last few years debugging code and not seeing a missing letter. http://www.dailywritingtips.com/cna-yuo-raed-tihs/

Answer (score 3):

This simply looks like Spell Error to me

```
<apex:page standardstylesheets="false"  showheader="false" sidebar="false"
standardController= " Merchandise__c" recordsetvariable="products">
```

> Please correct spell error of standardContoller to standardController

Comment: Well spotted.  Also, change `Merchandise_c` to `Merchandise__c`.